# Converting string to Date in Swift 4 fails in "Jailbroken" iPhone devices only. Why?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift4

Converting string to `Date` fails in jailbroken iPhone devices, but works fine in normal iPhone devices.

Note: I get the date string from a server in UTC format.

My code snippet is as below.

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")! as TimeZone

if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: result["timestamp"].stringValue) {
    //convert the UTC time to Mexico's local time if string to date conversion is successful
} else {  
      //failed to get Date from string (happens in Jailbroken devices only)
}
```

This code enters the `else` condition when it is run on jailbroken iPhone devices. My client reports that it happens only on jailbroken devices.
When I run the code on non-jailbroken iPhone devices, the string to date conversion works perfectly.

So, I am not getting this: how do I get a `Date` from a string on "jailbroken" iPhone devices?

Please do help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the initializer of `TimeZone` - `TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")` - instead of `NSTimeZone`.

Comment: @the4kman  - are you sure it will work for "jailbroken" iPhone devices?

Comment: This was just an advice from my side, not a solution for the particular problem you have - sorry if that was misleading.

Comment: @the4kman - Its ok buddy. The thing is that i don't have a jailbroken device to test this. So i have to upload to TestFlight and let the client test it with his jailbroken device and then only i will be able to reply you.

Comment: @the4kman - my client is still facing the issue. My client confirmed that he has a jailbroken iPhone device. He is using it in Mexico. Pls do help me out if any solution. How can i convert the UTC date to local date without being able to create a "Date" variable. Totally blocked over "jailbroken" device cases.